# WordPress Meta Query Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, metadata

I'm building a way form my users to "like" a post.

I'll have an array of users that have liked posts:

```
$user_ids = array(60, 61, 62, 63);
```

And then a post will have a post_meta that saves the user ID when the "like" button is clicked on a post, like so:

```
// Build array of user IDs that have liked this post
$likes = array(61, 62);

// Save array
update_post_meta($post->ID, likes, $likes);
```

So how can I return all posts liked by the users. This is how I'm doing it currently, which doesn't work.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'  => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'likes',
            'value'     => $user_ids,
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

This should return all posts that have '60, 61, 62, 63' saved in the posts 'likes' meta. But it returns 0 results.

Now, I think this is because WordPress serializes arrays when they are saved in a post_meta.

So, how do I a do a query like this? Is it even possible? Maybe I have to use the $wpdb class.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to pass your values as string in args like : $user_ids = array('60', '61', '62', '63'); ?

Comment: why you used `'relation'  => 'AND',` ? Because you not used  twor or more than two metakey

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one with `WP_Query` no need of relation just use the compare part with `IN`

```
 $user_ids = array(60, 61, 62, 63);
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_key' => 'likes',
   'post_status'       => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page'    => -1,
   'orderby'           => 'rand',       
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'likes',
           'value' => $user_ids, //array
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

> See the given example above "Time Parameters" Heading [**WP_Query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

OR by get_posts try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_query'        => array(

        array(
            'key'       => 'likes',
            'value'     => $user_ids,
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

OR by a custom query you can do as follows

```
global $wpdb;

$liked_posts=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE 
post_type='post' AND post_status ='publish' AND ID
 IN(
SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='likes' 
AND meta_value IN (".join(',',$user_ids).")
) ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Also don't store array of ids in one row instead loop through ids array and **normalize** your likes data manually Don't serialize data into a database field.  That's what [**Database_normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is for and insert each id in new row because

> Wordpress stores the meta values as strings. When you pass
>   `update_post_meta` an array, it automatically converts it to a string.
>   What you'll need to do is `unserialize` it when you attempt to read
>   the data but in mysql you can't `unserialize` column data in the query because mysql doesn't about the  serialization of  php

```
$likes = array(61, 62);

foerach($likes as $l){

update_post_meta($post->ID, "likes", $l);

}
```

And below is the query you have asked for in bounty comments

> ***If a $wpdb answer is given, then please elaborate on how to factor in category (include and exclude), and ignore posts by an array of IDs***

```
$liked_posts=$wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` wtr ON (wp.`ID`=wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN  `wp_term_taxonomy` wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` =wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
WHERE  wp.post_type='post' AND wp.post_status ='publish' AND wp.ID
 IN(
SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='likes' 
AND meta_value IN (".join(',',$user_ids).")
)  AND wp.ID NOT IN (100,101,102)
AND wtt.`term_id` IN(1,2,3) AND wtt.`term_id` NOT IN (4,5,6,)    
ORDER BY RAND() ");
```

I have used the `INNER JOINs` on `wp_term_relationships` and  `wp_term_taxonomy` the table `wp_term_relationships`stores the relation of posts and the taxonomy of category and the table `wp_term_taxonomy` have the taxonomy of the category and also the category id

Here is the part which covers the

**1. category (include and exclude)**

```
AND wtt.`term_id` IN(1,2,3) AND wtt.`term_id` NOT IN (4,5,6,)
```

**2. ignore posts by an array of IDs**

```
AND wp.ID NOT IN (100,101,102) 
or $postids =array(100,101,102);
AND wp.ID NOT IN (".join(',',$postids).")
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to run into problems with your current approach because, as you note, the ids are saved as serialized arrays in a single field. An easier approach would be to save each like as a single postmeta entry. So meta_key = "like" and meta_value = user ID.

So for storing the likes switch from update_post_meta to add_post_meta:

```
/** The fourth parameter, false, tells WP that there can be multiple
  * post_meta entries with the same meta_key. It's false by default, just here
  * here for reference
  */
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'like', $user_id, false);
```

Then to get posts liked by a specific user you would just do:

```
$liked_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta 
              WHERE meta_key = 'like' AND meta_value = $user_id");
```

To get results for a number of users at once, like user ID 4, 23, 39, etc.

```
$liked_posts_by_user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value as user_id, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) as posts FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wp_postmeta 
         WHERE meta_value IN('22','23','24') GROUP BY user_id
```

That will give you results like:

```
  user_id    posts
   23         1
   25         2,40,3
```

So just replace the IN portion of the query with your array of user ids.

Comment: This is a very good answer too, just not as in depth as the accepted one. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and i solved it using the serialize(), you can use ir in case that the vale you are working with is an integer here´s my example:

```
    $args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_meta_key',
            'value' => serialize(strval($my_id)),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

and that´s all, you hace your meta query ready.

Comment: YES MATE, serialize is the one !

Comment: If my `meta_value` like this:
`a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:12:"bundle_order";i:1;s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2187";s:11:"bp_quantity";i:1;}i:1;a:3:{s:12:"bundle_order";i:2;s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2189";s:11:"bp_quantity";i:1;}i:2;a:3:{s:12:"bundle_order";i:3;s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2186";s:11:"bp_quantity";i:1;}}`
How I can get **product_id = 2186** ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is right. But as you are storing user ids as a string your query wont work.
Save user id a single meta value for post.

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'like', $user_id, false);
```

and replace `'compare'   => 'IN'` with `'compare'   => 'LIKE'`