# WP_Query show a specific post and then show the rest

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I make it so in WP_Query I can show a post with a specific meta field first, and then show the rest as normal?

Edit:

I don't want to do multiple loops because I have check conditions within the loop that check if some post has already been in the loop, I cannot separate the loop because it'll break some of my check conditions.

Secondly, multiple loops are useful for separation of the content that's going to be looped. I just want the same content in side the loop, but just the loop ordered differently.

Here is my query for the loop

```
$queryVideoFirst = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'mirror',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'parentIDmirror',
            'value' => $postIDCheck,
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    )));
```

now I have a meta key called `video_provider` and I have a list of values for this meta key.

What I want done is the value `UploadAnime` in the `video_provider` meta key to be the first in the loop, and then the rest be outputted in a normal way.

So for example, if the query above pulled 5 `mirror`'s from the database, with the following `video_provider` meta values.

```
mirror 1: upload_ab
mirror 2: youtube
mirror 3: vimeo
mirror 4: UploadAnime
mirror 5: veevr
```

Then I want it to be ordered in such a way that `UploadAnime` is outputted first so it re-orders it like so

```
mirror4: UploadAnime
.
.
.
the rest
```

Comment: [**WordPress Meta Query Arrays**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036471/wordpress-meta-query-arrays/18092599#18092599)

Comment: Could you tell me specifically which answer provides the correct solution? The one that's labelled as correct answer doesn't put a post with a specific meta field value first, the orderby is rand for those queries.

Comment: @dianuj - that is a nice answer - but a bit complicated ..it can be done with simple multiple loops ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple loops like so ::

```
<?php 

$do_not_duplicate = array();
$do_not_duplicate2[] = array();// set array before loop to avoid errors 


// PUT YOUR ARGUMENTS HERE 
        $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'rand', // random order for those with specific meta
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  
                // Post type if needed ..
                'post_type' => array( 
                    'my_posttype', 
                    ), 
                'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key',
                'meta_value' => 'my_meta_value', 
                ),
        );


        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

                $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; // var for some juggling if needed in loop
                $do_not_duplicate_r[] = $post->ID; // but we really need array...

                // your loop here ...

        endwhile; 

            // end first condition now we set the new one 


        $args2 = array(
                'orderby' => 'rand', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  
                // Post type if needed ..
                'post_type' => array( 
                    'my_posttype', 
                    ), 
                'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key_2',
                'meta_value' => 'my_meta_value_2', 
                ),
        );


        $my_query_2 = new WP_Query($args2);

            while ($my_query_2->have_posts()) : $my_query_2->the_post();

                // if already counted, go ahead and ignore
                if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate_r)) continue; // This is important

                $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; // var for some juggling if needed in loop
                $do_not_duplicate_r[] = $post->ID; // but we really need array to continue from before...

            endwhile; 

        // now you can even continue with the normal loop or go on with n others ..

    if( have_posts() ){

                    while(have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    // do not forget to check DUPS
                    if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate_r)) continue; 

                    // your loop
                }

        }   

?>
```

**EDIT I** After comment

Or by using the [`order_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameter .

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product',
                                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                'meta_key' => 'my_string' ) );
```

But in your Original question you did not say what value it is , so for numeric values the syntax is :

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product',
                                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                                'meta_key' => 'my_num' ) );
```

That being said - I really do not understand why you added the `"do not want multiple loops"` condition to your question.
Multiple loops will allow you for a much greater control over the separation as it allow an easy visual distinction or logic separation ( different sorting for each type is only one example ).

Also , using the `order_by` parameters will force you to have that value all over ...

In your Original question , you did not specify any details as to what that value is and what is the final goal or aim you have ( .. and we all like when a question is lacking in crucial details that appear after the answers were already given .. )

Summing up - IMHO Multiple loops are still the way to go if you want more control and easier maintenance - and If not - then please specify in your question the reason as to why not.

Comment: The issue is I don't want it to be done through multiple loops :(

Comment: @Maaz 1 - Please specify why not 2 - That condition was not in your original question. 3 - Please specify the `meta_data` value type and  4 - please add any other conditions / details in the question

Comment: I've updated my question with a lot more information, sorry for the issues, I've also explained my reasoning behind not wanting multiple loops.
The two queries you provide after the Edit will order the loops by a meta_value, so in my case providing the meta_key as `video_provider` will just alphabetically order the posts looking at their meta values, this does not ensure that posts that have their meta values as `UploadAnime` will appear first.

Comment: right , but that you can sort easily inside the loop... and anyhow , you might want to rethink the values you give if you want to do everything in one query . one method I used before is just changing the value by appending prefix to `1_UploadAnime` and solve the problem. ( and I still did not understood your reasoning against multiple loops )

Comment: I ended up just creating another meta field for ordering :) Thanks for the help though :)