# query post with custom field value in Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

my custom field vardump() for a post with a good value (12 ) is :

```
 Custom_field = array(1) { [0]=> int(12) }
```

and my args for my query is :

```
$artistArg = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category_name' => 'oeuvres',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'Custom_field',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                'value' => array(12,29,34)
            )
        )

    );
```

It's not working... if I remove the value from the args it returns all the post, but when I pass the value in it returns nothing, I tried to change compare to "=" or "IN" also...I guess I'm doing something wrong here...(and I also tried with a "non array" custom field and everything works fine...)
thank you

**EDIT :** 
As I don't find the solution right now i just do that :

```
<?php
//Get the value
$authorId = get_the_ID();
//query the post with the good meta_key
$artistArg = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category_name' => 'oeuvres',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'artiste'
            )
        )

    );
//In the query I just filter the results with the given array of the custom field...
$artDisplay = new WP_Query( $artistArg );

            // The Loop
            if ( $artDisplay->have_posts() ) {
                    echo '<h2>Art: </h2><ul id="discover">';
                while ( $artDisplay->have_posts() ) {
                    $artDisplay->the_post();
                    $artiste = get_field('artiste');
                    if ($artiste[0] == $authorId):
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo "<div class='thumbDiscover'>";
                    echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>";
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumb');
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</div><span>";
                    echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>";
                    the_title();
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</span>";

                    echo '</li>';
                    endif;
                }
                    echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }
    endif;
            ?>
```

So it's not perfect...if anyone have a proper solution, 
Thank you

Comment: remove `,` after `'value' => array(12,29,34),` should be `'value' => array(12,29,34)`

Comment: thank you, but no, it doesn't do anything ( I agree with you though that it's more correct...) I don't have any php error...and if I remove 'value' => array(12,29,34) totally I do get all the post with a meta_key that is "Custom_field"

Comment: echo $artDisplay->request, see what's sql is like..

Comment: Compare exists do not checks value parameter, You have to use IN, also add "type" in meta query as NUMERIC http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query
Also can you make sure, you are storing int for meta key as value and not array

Comment: I did try "IN" and it doesn't work neither - @Andrew I did that and the request seems normal :
AND (wpDB_postmeta.meta_key = 'artiste' )
(I can't paste all the query here, anything that could be interesting in it ?)

Comment: so @moabi, if you run the request in mysql db directly, it gives results?

Comment: no, it only gives result if I get some posts as shown in the second query; otherwhise I don't get anything...

Comment: use `'meta_query' => array('key' => 'artiste')`

Comment: @KrunalShah thanks, I tried it also : 
$artistArg = array(
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'category_name' => 'oeuvres',
   'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key' => 'artiste',
              'compare' => 'IN',
              'type' => 'numeric',
              'value' => array(12, 0)
          )
      )
And the thing is when I had "O" to the array, the post is shown... ? could be a nice clue no ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try passing array directly in values

```
$artistArg = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category_name' => 'oeuvres',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'Custom_field',
                'value' => array(12,29,34)
            )
        )

    );
```

Comment: no luck neither...I tried with numeric and string (eg : array(12,'12') or array(12,22)...I guess I'll figure it next year, I'll post the answer if I find out !!!

Answer (score 0):

As [sated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> `value (string|array)` - Custom field value (Note: Array support is
>   limited to a compare value of 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT
>   BETWEEN') (<s>This value may be omitted when using the 'EXISTS' or 'NOT
>   EXISTS' comparisons in WordPress 3.5 and up</s>)

So you may not using `'compare' => 'EXISTS'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$artistArg = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'Custom_field',
    'category_name' => 'oeuvres',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Custom_field',
              'compare'   => 'IN'
            'value' => array(12,29,34)
        )
    )

);
```

pass the 'meta_key' => 'Custom_field' in the array [see the stack over flow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036471/wordpress-meta-query-arrays)

Comment: thank you, but no luck...(nb: you have forgotten a coma after 'IN')