# Wordpress: Check data by using get_results

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have problem to check data if its found or not, Bellow i have table in Wordpress called (postmeta), and store data like :

```
meta_id    : 27327
post_id    : 4876
meta_key   : rtb
meta_value : a:20:{s:5:"party";i:1;s:5:"email";s:18:"test@gmail.com";s:5:"phone";s:10:"05921655517";s:8:"catofres";s:6:"single";s:9:"tabletype";s:8:"openarea";s:14:"validationcode";i:8407704;s:11:"frindsname1";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile1";s:0:"";s:11:"frindsname2";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile2";s:0:"";s:11:"frindsname3";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile3";s:0:"";s:11:"frindsname4";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile4";s:0:"";s:11:"frindsname5";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile5";s:0:"";s:11:"frindsname6";s:0:"";s:13:"frindsmobile6";s:0:"";s:15:"date_submission";i:1525176468;s:2:"ip";s:10:"37.8.85.11";}
```

Now the problem how can do SQL query that check if the data (test@gmail.com , 8407704) found it this table or not ,,,

I try this query :

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'rtb' ", OBJECT );
```

But I could not complete the check in the Query

Comment: why are you not using get_post_meta()?

Comment: @Tobias how can use it,, as you see the email and validationcode are in one row ,, can you tell me ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: its not true ,, idont have post id ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;

$metas = $wpdb->get_results( 
 $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = %s", 'rtb')
 );

print_r($metas);
```

try also

```
   if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, 'rtb' ) ) {
   $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rtb', true );
    }
```

Comment: how can check if `email: test@gmail.com` and  `validationcode:8407704` are in `meta_value`

Comment: you can check into your result array using foreach $metas.

Comment: a wpdb call is the wrong way...for exactly this is get_post_meta8

Comment: wpdb call is the wrong way...it will work but you should do it with get_post_meta()..see the docu: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: its not good ,, if i use get_post_meta its return me an array , but i need to check if `test@gmail.com` are in `meta_value` and you must see what the `meta_value` have value ,,, its array

Comment: try this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036471/wordpress-meta-query-arrays

Comment: @TechnoDeviser its not true check in foreach ,,, its condition , i need check in query to get only one date

Comment: how can get $post_id ? i put the code in function.php .. so i cannot use get_post_meta

Comment: i try your answer and get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @TechnoDeviser  are you see the value of `meta_value` its an array , and how can ccheck my request in this array without have post id

Comment: if (in_array(test@gmail.com, $metas))
{
echo "test@gmail.com found in the array";
}

Comment: its not work ,,, i try `if (in_array(test@gmail.com, $metas)) { echo "test@gmail.com found in the array"; }else { echo "not fount";}` its print not found ,,, but email in `meta_value `

Comment: I know the reason for the error, the error is that the table contains more than one field and it is here only checking in one field, and leaving others